# error while intercepting a request

Tags: java, testing, networking, burp

I am using `Burp suite's` proxy feature. I have changed firefox settings as:

**options > network > settings**

[image]

But when i run `http://localhost:8080/project_name` in the browser in order to intercept the request,it gives following error:

`Burp proxy error: invalid client request received: first line of request did not contain an absolute URL - try enabling invisible proxy support`

Can anybody provide me any hint why this error is coming?

Answer (score 5):

You probably didn't turn on "Invisible Proxy Support." On Burp Suite, go to `Proxy` tab and then `Options` sub-tab. In the `Proxy Listeners` box located at the top, you'll see the listener you are using. Select it, click the `Edit` button, and go to `Request Handling` tab. On that page at the bottom, you'll see "Support invisible proxying" checkbox. Check that box to turn on the invisible proxy support.

Oh, before I did that, I installed Firefox Plug-n-Hack add-on, which you can obtain at https://github.com/mozmark/ringleader/blob/master/fx_pnh.xpi

I never changed anything on the firefox setting you showed by the way.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

as @yoppuyoppu said, Burp's Proxy listener can support `**Invisible Proxy**`.  But this feature is for Proxy unaware clients (like cURL, OpenSSL generated requests in mobile apps).

You should NOT require Invisible Proxy as you are using a Browser which is Proxy Aware.

Great article from Burp on this topic.
https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_invisible.html